# Can redundant tests be obsoleted and dropped in TDD methodology?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, tdd, methodology

I have two functions, `foo` and `bar`.

```
function foo() {
    if (arguments.length !== 1) {
        throw new TypeError('only one argument expected');
    }

    do work;
}

function bar() {
    if (arguments.length !== 3) {
        throw new TypeError('exactly three arguments expected');
    }

    do work;
}
```

These functions were created according to TDD — e.g. tests were written first, then functions were implemented to make tests pass. List of tests:

1. `foo()` is defined
2. `foo()` does its job right
3. `foo()` throws `TypeError` when given wrong number of arguments
4. `bar()` is defined
5. `bar()` does its job right
6. `bar()` throws `TypeError` when given wrong number of arguments

As you see, these functions both have duplicating functionality — they are testing for correctness of arguments each on it's own. As this check is going to be very common among my functions, and may go more complex (check for argument count to be in some range, check argument types etc), I've decided to move it out into separate decorator function `check`.

So I've written tests for `check` and implemented `check` itself.

Now refactoring step — I've took an advantage of `check`, so functions now look as follows:

```
foo = check(1, function() {
    do work;
});

bar = check(3, function() {
    do work;
});
```

What should I do now to tests that check for `foo()` and `bar()` take correct number of arguments? Can I drop them?

When I implement function `buzz()`, that makes use of `check()` immediately (as it's now used as way to define functions), do I have to write test for it to take correct number of arguments? I'm hesitating, because this test will be always green, as all job is done within decorator, so is there any need for test?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would avoid to keep multiple unit tests that check the same code, because in the future:

1. If you'll intentionally change the `check` function in a way that break your tests, you'll have to change 2 tests instead of one.
2. If you unintentionally break the `check`, you'll get two failures: one referring to `foo` and one referring to `bar`, and it could not be obvious that what is broken is the `check` function.

So, I would keep only one set of tests, explicitly named as tests for the `check` function, and even better, don't use function of your program to test them (not `foo` neither `bar` in your example) but use a fake function used only for tests purposes.

In this way, you can in future alter `foo` or `bar` to use, e.g., a check2 function without break tests of check function

This is, according to me, the best theoretical approach to go, but be pragmatic: don't try to follow this way if you don't expect to use the `check` function in a great portion of your code: your target has to have the main program running smoothly, not a beautiful set of tests...

Comment: I already use 'fake' function local to test scope to test if `check` correctly passes arguments inside wrapped function, and returns function result — e.g. I don't use any real function to test `check` validity. Is that what you proposed?

Comment: Yes. If you already have tests for `check` function, remove tests 3 and 6 from your set, they are redundant. If you're seeking perfection,   I would code a mockup for `check` function, make it injectable, and I just check that is called inside `foo` and `bar`

Comment: But as @carousel pointed out, don't try to test everything, or your ending in spending too time testing simple things that will never get broken: I suggest that you just remove the tests and give for granted that foo and bar call `check` function

Answer (score 1):

Classical TDD concepts needs some additional modifications to apply them to dynamic language like Javascript (due to lack of classes, specific use of closures ...) That's way we have such testing libraries like Jasminejs.
I can't tell you explicitly what to do with your functions, but I know that everything needs not to be tested. Some things really are so obvious that they just need some way of sanity check. Rule of thumb is to test things that can break. For example validations, database access, user input...

Comment: As I'm quite new to TDD — this is effectively my first project I want to do solely with strictest TDD possible — I'm hesitative about 'no line of code should be written without test for it' approach violation. Like if I only test for what can be broken, how is that different from plain unit-testing?

Comment: Implementing TDD is a hard task. It needs time, work and patiance.
The hardest thing and final goal is to design your application by testing. There is a TDD mantra (red,green,refactor) But small steps are required. If you are new to TDD I would recommend you to be familiar with some background and simple examples. Calculator testing is bread and butter of TDD. Also there are TDD katas. Testing is a geeky skill :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are on the right path, TDD make more evident the code duplication (the checking parameters code its duplication that must be removed with or without TDD) and you listen to your test and separate the responsibility of checking, now you have two responsibilities:

- checking parameters, with his own set of test.
- The work of the functions, that have his own set test that asume always correct inputs.

At a unit testing level this is perfect i think, perhaps in other point you need some integration or systems test that checks that your composing correctly the functions with his checkers.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a separate statement, you need a test. So in your case, you need to keep the tests that require that both `foo()` and `bar()` use the `check` function. These tests may be simpler than the original tests that you wrote: For example they may only check that an error is thrown, without looking into the error message.

Should the check function now be broken to for example do nothing, there would be multiple tests that detect this. That is not an issue because you would put the test for the `check` function at the top, and so the first failure will directly point to the root cause.